# Pycharm Memory Error when I read a 7GB sqlite3 File with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, memory

I am trying to count number of duplicate rows from a file "train.db" comprising of 7GB. My laptop has 8GB RAM. Below is the code I have used to obtain the results. When I run the code, I get the Error as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>   File "C:/Users/tahir/PycharmProjects/stopwordsremovefile/stopwordsrem.py", line 13, in <module>
>     df_no_dup = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Title, Body, Tags, COUNT(*) as cnt_dup FROM trainingdata GROUP by Title, Body, Tags', con)
>   File "C:\Users\tahir\PycharmProjects\stopwordsremovefile\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 332, in read_sql_query
>     chunksize=chunksize,
>   File "C:\Users\tahir\PycharmProjects\stopwordsremovefile\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1658, in read_query
>     data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)
>   File "C:\Users\tahir\PycharmProjects\stopwordsremovefile\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1671, in _fetchall_as_list
>     result = cur.fetchall()
> MemoryError
> ```

Process finished with exit code 1

Following is the code I am using:-

```py
import os
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

from pandas import DataFrame

if os.path.isfile('train.db'):
    start = datetime.now()
    con = sqlite3.connect('train.db')
    con.text_factory = lambda x: str(x, 'iso-8859-1')
    df_no_dup = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Title, Body, Tags, COUNT(*) as cnt_dup FROM trainingdata GROUP by Title, Body, Tags', con)
    con.close()
    print("Time taken to run this cell:", datetime.now() - start)
else:
    print("Please download train.db file")
```

Comment: Don't use pandas, use sqlite directly, and access the results a row at a time instead of trying to load them all at once?

Comment: Could you please help me by suggesting the right code? As you have seen the whole code so you can suggest the right one. I am beginner with Python and your help will be much appreciated.